# android layout: This tag and its children can be replaced by one <TextView/> and a compound drawable

Tags: android, layout

When I run layout on a specific XML file, I get this:

```
 This tag and its children can be replaced by one <TextView/> 
and a compound drawable
```

What change should be done for the following xml code:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/name_layout"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:background="@drawable/grouplist_single_left_grey_area" >
                <ImageView android:id="@+id/photo_image"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/thumbnail_width"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/thumbnail_height"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dip"
                    android:paddingTop="5dip"
                    android:paddingRight="5dip"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dip"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@*android:drawable/nopicture_thumbnail"
                    android:background="@drawable/photo_highlight" />
                <TextView android:id="@+id/name"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dip"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
            </LinearLayout>
```

This is how it looks like on the screen:

[image]

The camera icon is the default. Clicking on that will give the user an option to choose another image.

Comment: +1, because this situation looks more complex than can be handled by compound drawable. If you hadn't accepted Romain's answer, you might have gotten a more in-depth answer.

Answer (score 173, accepted):

To expand on Romain Guy's answer, here is an example.

Before:

```
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"  
android:padding="5dp" >

<TextView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="My Compound Button" />

<ImageView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/my_drawable" />
</LinearLayout>
```

After:

```
<TextView  
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="My Compound Button" 
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/my_drawable" android:padding="5dp" />
```

Comment: Nifty. But what if I need to set properties on the drawable, like define it to 60dip x 60dip?

Comment: Hey look at that, all I had to do was search. http://stackoverflow.com/a/6671544/1224741

Comment: @KyleClegg, It is possible with a custom library. See my answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/41347470/2308720

Comment: The last commit of this project was three years ago, it is not maintained, I guess.

Answer (score 107):

Merge the `TextView` and the `ImageView` into one, by using TextView's `setCompoundDrawable*()` methods, or using `android:drawableLeft`.

Comment: Could you point me to an example illustrating how that can be done? I am not sure how all the attributes in the ImageView can be accommodated in android:drawableLeft.

Thank you

Comment: What about ImageViews attributes like scaleType ?

Comment: How do I increase the gap between the image and the text?

Comment: setCompoundDrawable*() not working, use setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds() instead

Comment: @Kimo_do, `setCompoundDrawable()` will not take care of your drawable as it is, you have to call `setBounds` on it (see [API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawables%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29)).

For setting it, you can get the previous bounds using the `TextView.getCompoundDrawables()`, accessing the correct drawable index and finally calling `getBounds()`.

Answer (score 20):

Thought I would try to get some extra puntos for this as well: you can add padding between the image and the text using `android:drawablePadding`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/6671544/1224741

Answer (score 4):

Add `tools:ignore="UseCompoundDrawables"` to `<LinearLayout>`.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes it is possible to replace `ImageView` (or multiple) and `TextView` with one `TextView` with compound drawable(s). There are NOT many parameters which can be applied to compound drawable using native API and this [TextViewRichDrawable library](https://github.com/a-tolstykh/textview-rich-drawable), but **if you can manage one TextView instead of using LinearLayout you should definitely use it**.

The list of attributes and parameters which can be applied to compound drawables:

Size: (**YES, really**):

```
<com.tolstykh.textviewrichdrawable.TextViewRichDrawable
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Some text"
    app:compoundDrawableHeight="24dp"
    app:compoundDrawableWidth="24dp"/>
```

Even **set vector resource** as drawable:

```
<com.tolstykh.textviewrichdrawable.TextViewRichDrawable
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Some text"
    app:drawableTopVector="@drawable/some_vector_drawble"
    app:drawableEndVector="@drawable/another_vector_drawable" />
```

Drawable's Padding using native API `android:drawablePadding` -> [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:drawablePadding)

**Here is an example:**

[image: textView rich drawable]

Answer (score 2):

A `LinearLayout` which contains an `ImageView` and a `TextView` can 
 be more efficiently handled as a compound drawable (a single 
 `TextView`, using the `drawableTop`, `drawableLeft`, `drawableRight` 
     and/or `drawableBottom` attributes to draw one or more images 
 adjacent to the text).

If the two widgets are offset from each other with margins, this 
 can be replaced with a `drawablePadding` attribute.

There's a lint quickfix to perform this conversion in the Eclipse 
 plugin.

From: Android Official API docs!

Answer (score 2):

You can refer this code for example

```
<TextView
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_gravity="center"
 android:text="@string/myName"
 android:textAlignment="center"
 android:textColor="@color/myColor"
 app:drawableTopCompat="@drawable/image_name" />
```

Answer (score 1):

When I followed the code above, text inside the TextView doesn't set properly. 
You need to set its gravity to center|start to achieve what shown in the asked question.

The textview looks like this:

```
   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/export_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/up_arrow"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/up_arrow"
        android:gravity="center|start"
        android:text="....."
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size15" >
    </TextView>
```

Answer (score 1):

the latest correct way at time of writing to add a compound drawable is using `app:drawableStartCompat` rather than `android:drawableLeft`.

```
<TextView 
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="My Compound Button"
    android:drawablePadding="5dp"
    app:drawableStartCompat="@drawable/my_drawable" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change the ImageView and TextView, you can change the version in the AndroidManifest.xml as:

```
    <uses-sdk`
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" 
    />
```

If your version is  android:targetSdkVersion="17" change it s "18".

Hope this will rectify. I did it and got it right

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is an efficient solution. But using `<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>` to wrap the `imageView` and `TextView` instead of `<LinearLayout>` will fix this error. Also by using `LinearLayoutCompat`, you will be able to adjust the image's width and height which you can't when using a `drawableRight`, `drawableLeft`, `drawableTop` or `drawableBottom` inside a `TextView`.

Answer (score 0):

This warning is rather misleading. You can use a compound drawable using a `TextView` as others have suggested but it doesn't necessarily give you the desired result. You have very littler control over how you want your button to look like using a compound drawable, so it is better to just add `tools:ignore="UseCompoundDrawables"` and ignore this warning.

Answer (score -2):

Another approach is embed the ViewImage into another LinearLayout (allow handle it with alone id):

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <LinearLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >    
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/blue_3"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="16dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/tvPrompt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/xy" />
```

Comment: Now what would be the advantage of this? And why are you setting the namespace twice?

Answer (score -5):

```
    This tag and its children can be replaced by one <TextView/> and a compound drawable



    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:contentDescription="."
        android:padding="3dp" 
        android:src="@drawable/tab_home_btn">
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"       
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="首页"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff">
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```