# Making Custom RadioButton with image on center

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to my custom RadioButton that I trying to make to look like this:

[image: Expected Result]

So I did custom drawables that respond to the RadioButton status and used it as background. This is alright.

The problem is that I'm not been able to center the images that I set through the `android:button` atribute.

Here is how I'm trying to use it in my layout.

```
<RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/presenter_options"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        >

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:button="@drawable/cluster_centered"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/presenter_radiobutton_left"
            />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/presenter_radiobutton_right"
            android:button="@drawable/fire"
            />

</RadioGroup>
```

With this I'm getting this as result:

[image: Actual result]

I've already tried to define a drawable that sets the gravity to center, but nothing changed. Here is the custom drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/cluster" android:gravity="center"/>
    </item>
</selector>
```

So, how could I center the button images?

PS: I can't set each kind of button as background because it'll be dynamic in the future, so the only thing that could be in background is the blue shape.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My solution was to set `android:button=@null`, then set the image that I want into the `android:drawableLeft` attribute. So my RadioButton code is like this:

```xml
<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/presenter_radiobutton_left"
    android:button="@null"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/fire"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

"on center" solution is

...

```
<RadioButton>
...
android:button="@null"
android:foreground="@drawable/your_selector_for_center_drawable"
android:background="@drawable/your_selector_for_background_drawable"
android:foregroundGravity="center"
```