# The Gap between "Image" and "Text" of a button is too much

Tags: java, android, eclipse, user-interface, android-relativelayout

I have developed an app, following is the code

This is the code of this app

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".HomeScreen" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:stretchColumns="*"
        android:weightSum="4" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/fBtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="@string/fStr" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/rBtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="@string/rStr" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/sBtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="@string/sStr" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/cBtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="@string/cStr" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/aBtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="@string/aStr" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/lBtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="@string/lStr" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/oBtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="@string/oStr" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/tBtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="@string/tStr" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/eBtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="@string/eStr" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/dBtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="@string/dStr" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/hBtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="@string/hStr" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/aaBtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="@string/aStr" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**strings.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="fStr">Fffffffff</string>
<string name="rStr">Rrrrrr</string>
<string name="sStr">Ssssss       </string>
<string name="lStr">Lllll</string>
<string name="oStr">Oooooooooooo</string>
<string name="tStr">Ttttt</string>
<string name="eStr">Eeeeee</string>
<string name="dStr">Dddddddddd</string>
<string name="cStr">Cccccccc</string>
<string name="hStr">Hhhh</string>
<string name="aStr">Aaaaaaaaaa aaaa</string>

</resources>
```

This app has an issue.

1. The gap between button image and text is too much, specially in 5.1 WVGA screen. It does the same look in my mobile, which has the screen size of 4.5 inches

Following is the image

[image]

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: I had this problem before, the way I fixed it was have a sperate imageview and textview for each items, wrapped in a layout (Linear for me) and put the onclick event on the layout. There's also a drawablePadding attr which might help also

Comment: @TomHart: Drawable padding did not work.

Comment: Yeah it didn't for me either, that's why I needed to have separate layouts for each button.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use LinearLayout ;

```
![<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".HomeScreen" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.33"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/fBtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_weight="0.33"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="@string/fStr" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/rBtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_weight="0.33"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="@string/rStr" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/sBtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_weight="0.33"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="@string/sStr" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.33"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/fBtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_weight="0.33"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="@string/fStr" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/rBtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_weight="0.33"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="@string/rStr" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/sBtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_weight="0.33"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="@string/sStr" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.33"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/fBtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_weight="0.33"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="@string/fStr" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/rBtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_weight="0.33"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="@string/rStr" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/sBtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_weight="0.33"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="@string/sStr" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.33"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/fBtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_weight="0.33"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="@string/fStr" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/rBtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_weight="0.33"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="@string/rStr" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/sBtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_weight="0.33"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="@string/sStr" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try to use android:drawablePadding, and android:paddingLeft and android:paddingRight

refer to [android:drawableLeft margin and/or padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337371/androiddrawableleft-margin-and-or-padding/3337553#3337553)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a modified version which will reduce the size of the buttons, and center them inside their row, and gets rid of the useless RelativeLayout parent (as Lint was probably pointing out to you) :

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:stretchColumns="*"
    android:weightSum="4"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".HomeScreen">

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/fBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight=".3"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="bla" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/rBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight=".3"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="bla" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight=".3"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="bla" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight=".3"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="bla" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/aBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight=".3"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="bla" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/lBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight=".3"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="bla" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/oBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight=".3"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="bla" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/tBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight=".3"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="bla" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/eBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight=".3"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="bla" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight=".3"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="bla" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/hBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight=".3"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="bla" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/aaBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_weight=".3"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="bla" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```