# How to put gap between Text and ImageView in EditText in android?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am using the EditText with drawableLeft property and set ImageView in Right side for ClearText. My Question is  how to put gap between text and Imageview in EditText?

Please help me.

Actually I have Like this,My Screenshot is,
[image]

Actually I want to Like this,
[image]

Create Gap Between Text and ImageView. How it is Possible?.

My xml file is,

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edtSearch"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_margin="5dip"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/search"
            android:drawablePadding="10dip"
            android:hint="Find"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:singleLine="true" >
        </EditText>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgSearchClear"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/edtSearch"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:src="@drawable/clear" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: why you are not use linear layout with horizontal orientation ?

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337371/androiddrawableleft-margin-and-or-padding

Comment: Becuase put ImageView wihin EdiiTtext. so...

Comment: You can use `android:maxLength=""` for `EditText`.

Comment: Do you need to right to edittext or above on edittext?

Comment: @Pragna ImageView above on Edittext?

Comment: Yes ImageView Above on EditText but If write Some Text then text is  not overwrite on Imageview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay i got your Question now...you have to use Search view instead of edittext

[Here is link:- Check it out](http://sampleprogramz.com/android/searchview.php)

Only this is a solution  of your problem

Comment: Thanks for help me, I got Quite Solution but I have one problem that First time display only searchbox(See Screenshot 1) and click on searchbox then after display  Fully Details(See Screenshot 2).See My updated Question please and guide me.

Comment: apologies but i don't get you what you exactly want to do

Comment: See you My First and Second Screenshot in My Updated Question. First Display only SearchBox and Click on SearchBox then Display SearchView. and I want First Time Display SearchView. Please See Screenshot. I consider that Screenshot 2 is SearchView.If you have any problem in Question then ask me.

Comment: when you are using search view than it just show edittext and search icon but when you click on editext inside search view and start writing than it shows cross button

Comment: No but in may case, I using the SearchView but Display Only Search icon and Click on Search Icon then Display Search Icon , EditText and Cross Button. Why Do this?I using your demo. Nothing Else.

Answer (score 1):

i am using `LinearLayout` for this

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/chatText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:padding="8dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/buttonSend"
        android:layout_width="50sp"
        android:layout_height="50sp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" /> 
   </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem a while ago fixed it with `drawablePadding`

Answer (score 0):

**Hello**

Use Linear layout with weight instead of Relative as m showing below:-

```
<LinearLayout 
      width
      hight
      orientation="horizontal">

       <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edtSearch"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
             android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_margin="5dip"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/search"
            android:drawablePadding="10dip"
            android:hint="Find"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:singleLine="true" >
        </EditText>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgSearchClear"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
             android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:src="@drawable/clear" />


       </LinearLayout>
```

if you found any issue regarding this please let me know..i love to help you

or in relative layou you can use drawable padding

Spartacus thanks :)

I can try to implement your code but It Like this,[image]

and I want to Like this,[image]

Answer (score 0):

Set the right padding of `EditText` to the width of Clear button. Set all the dimension in dimen folder so that it will be compatible with all device sizes.