# How can I add padding on background image? | Android

Tags: android

I added an image on my button with `android:drawableTop` line. But image is too much above, I want to add padding to my background drawable image. How can I do that?

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oW587.png)

```
<Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="165dp"
            android:text="take note"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/note_al"
            android:background="#51A39D"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:textSize="30dp" />
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to say *exactly* where you want padding in relation to your drawable and button?  Can also maybe show some images showing what you want?

Comment: I just want to add padding my background image.

Comment: see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337371/androiddrawableleft-margin-and-or-padding)

Comment: @KaanKaraca where *exactly* do you want the padding?  All around the image? Or just in between the button and the image? Please be specific what your "before" and "after" looks like.

Comment: [just here](http://i.imgur.com/QJNL6uP.png)

Comment: Interesting but I solved my problem. `android:paddingTop` works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `android:drawablePadding`.