# Is there a better way to align the text in different buttons in Android?

Tags: android, xml, button, alignment

It is my firs time that I try to design a good UI instead of debugging apps, so I am new to this type of stuff.

I have three buttons under each other and the text should be aligned correctly. So that the "F" of Favorites starts at the same horizontal point as the "E" of Equalizer.
The way I did it, is not satisfying. I worked with `paddingEnd` and just tried out until it looked almost equal on the horizontal axis.

One other idea was to make the gravity `center_vertical|left` and instead use `drawablePadding`. This did not work because the width of the buttons is defined as `match_parent`. But also when I change the buttons to `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` and remove `android:paddingStart` and `android:paddingEnd` for testing, it does not work.

I got these info out of [android:drawableLeft margin and/or padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337371/androiddrawableleft-margin-and-or-padding/40305801)

There should be a way to make it "easy" to fulfill the design I require. Has someone an idea what I am making wrong and has a solution for me?

The code of the xml layout file and a screenshot of the result are attached.

If something else is required to solve this question, then just ask me straight away.

[Screenshot of the buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpJa1.png)

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/menu"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:paddingEnd="0.3dip"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/favButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:insetTop="1dp"
            android:insetBottom="1dp"
            android:paddingStart="50dp"
            android:paddingEnd="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_bxs_heart"
            android:text="@string/favorites"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="16sp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/eqzButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:insetTop="1dp"
            android:insetBottom="1dp"
            android:paddingStart="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_equalizer"
            android:text="@string/equalizer"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="16sp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/settingsButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:insetTop="1dp"
            android:insetBottom="1dp"
            android:paddingStart="50dp"
            android:paddingEnd="27dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_settings"
            android:text="@string/settings"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="16sp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Try to use the material native library https://material.io/develop/android/components/buttons And another tip, in this case to could to use a constraint layout as parent group view and remove the LinearLayout

Comment: What does it mean: *the text should be aligned correctly* ?

Comment: @ManuelMato I When using it as an icon, it is working with the ``iconPadding``. With that I should be able to align all text the same. @GabrieleMariotti I meant that the "F" of Favorites starts at the same horizontal point as the "E" of Equalizer.