# This tag and its children can be replaced by one and a compound drawable

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:orientation="horizontal"

 >

<ImageView

    android:id="@+id/file_icon"
    style="@style/fileChooserIcon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/desc" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/file_name"
    style="@style/fileChooserName"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     />
```

Error:`This tag and its children can be replaced by one <TextView/> and a compound drawable`

i am new to android and don't exactly understand whats the error. certain solution sad to make it compound but didn't get it.

Comment: it's not an error ... it's [lint](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint) hint

Comment: will it affect the project?

Comment: it is better for us to listen those hints (check Raghav Sood's answer) ... but sometimes we can ignore 'em ... in this particular example you can get performance boost(if you use the hint) especially if you are using this layout in ListView

Comment: why downvote? this is a valid question

Comment: possible duplicate of [android layout: This tag and its children can be replaced by one <TextView/> and a compound drawable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214424/android-layout-this-tag-and-its-children-can-be-replaced-by-one-textview-and)

Answer (score 6):

Merge the TextView and the ImageView into one, by using TextView's `setCompoundDrawable*()` methods, or using `android:drawableLeft`.

Example:

You go from

```
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"  
android:padding="5dp" >

<TextView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="My Compound Button" />

<ImageView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/my_drawable" />
</LinearLayout>
```

To

```
<TextView  
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="My Compound Button" 
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/my_drawable"
    android:padding="5dp" />
```

Comment: one doubt:am i supposed to change the entire code or just textview and imageview?

Comment: You can replace that entire LinearLayout element.

Comment: @Kirarahul You can set it programmatically using setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds() - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(int, int, int, int)

Comment: how to set the size of image here

Comment: how to change image size & tint color after compound drawable?